# Repeatable Custom Schedule in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, schedule

I'm working on creating a Rails app that allows users to set availability Sunday through Saturday, with a start time, end time, and location (simple string).  I have an User object and I'm unsure of how to continue.  I know I could have a large set of Time objects like so:

```
class User
    field :mondayStartTime, :type => Time
    field :mondayEndTime, :type => Time
    field :mondayLocation, :type => String
    field :tuesdayStartTime, :type => Time
    field :tuesdayEndTime, :type => Time
    field :tuesdayLocation, :type => String
    ...
    field :sundayEndTime, :type => Time
    field :sundayLocation, :type => String
end
```

However, this seems terribly inefficient, though creating another unique object class seems just as bad and only results in more lines of code.  Is there an easier way of implementing start/end times for a Sunday through Saturday schedule?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first glance, I'd create an "Availability" model/class (or something less prone to misspelling like "Schedule")  with the attributes of start_at, end_at, location, and day_of_week - and have that class belong to the User (and with the User having a "has_many :availabilities" or "has_many :schedules").  That seems (again at first glance) to be the most efficient and easiest to get the data back out - and you can use that separate class to do things like grouping schedules/availabilities together more easily.

Comment: I like BriteLite's answer, but yours might work better.  Doing dates as something like an enum (does Ruby have enums?) would make it easier to select availability by day of the week instead of something like 3.days.from_now.  I will implement something today, and then whoever gave the easier implementation gets the checkmark :)

Comment: Going to go with your answer.  When the server is hit to show availability, I can pull the availability that matches Time.now.wday and present that to the user.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Have you thought about creating objects for each day of the week, that have a start, end and location property?

Or perhaps, a Jobs object(model) that has fields for start time, end time, and location.

This way it would be possible to do, has_many :jobs and then you can either narrow down, by day, or select by a particular day. The narrowing down should be feasible with the ruby Time Class or ActiveSupport class (3.days.from_now, etc).

```
irb(main):001:0> require 'active_support/all'
=> true
irb(main):002:0> 2.days.ago
=> 2012-04-03 08:30:31 -0700
irb(main):003:0> 2.days.from_now
=> 2012-04-07 08:33:01 -0700
```

EDITED TO SHOW ACTIVE SUPPORT TIME CLASS

Comment: doh! wrote my answer as BriteLite was posting theirs - what they said! :-)

Comment: This definitely makes sense, but I'm confused as to how I would narrow down once the week has passed.  For example, if I have a user set availability for Tuesdays, how would I check for availability now?  Technically it's set for 2 days in the past.  Would I just have to add 7.days to any scheduling found in the past?

Comment: Check: http://as.rubyonrails.org/ 
Under the Module ActiveSupport::CoreExtensions::Date::Calculations section.

Also you can try on irb console:
require 'active_support/all'

irb(main):002:0> 2.days.ago
=> 2012-04-03 08:30:31 -0700

that just allowed me to move 2 days back. Perhaps this is what you were asking?

irb(main):003:0> 2.days.from_now
=> 2012-04-07 08:33:01 -0700